# Rewrite URL of Specific Post of Custom Type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm attempting to implement a rule for a **single instance** of a post (custom) so that instead of it appearing at `mysite.com/post-type/post-title` it becomes simply `mysite.com/about`. I don't want a rule which is going to affect anything other than this specific post and the Q/As that've found so far all aim to create wider rules.

Is this possible with `add_rewrite_rule`? How might a rule like that look?

Comment: Not possible to create a rule that doesn’t clash with the root pages rule, unless you add per-post rules for each

Comment: Thanks for reading, @milo. I need to create the rule for just a single instance so creating a specific rule per-post on this occasion would only require a single rule. Can you suggest how it might look?